# VBA script to copy data from CSV files to specific sheets in Excel based on the file name

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import, filenames

I have a master template excel file with 12 sheets named ‘DecisionEvent’, ‘invoices’ etc.

The Sheets have column headers.

Each week I must manually copy and paste data from 2 csv files into each of the 12 sheets.

The headers in the CSV files match the headers in the master template other than one additional column at the end of one of the sheets.

The csv files have a naming convention such as:

3724_DecisionEventWFAD_20230521060003

3725_DecisionEventWFCH_20230521060010

I want to achieve the following:

In the DecisionEvent sheet -> check the source folder (containing the csv files) for any filename containing DecisionEventWFAD and copy all the data in the csv file to the first blank row.

Then

In the DecisionEvent sheet -> check the source folder for any filename containing DecisionEventWFCH and copy all the data in the csv file to the first blank row.

Here is the script that I have been given, but I get a runtime error 9 (subscript out of range) at the line:  *Set decisionEventSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DecisionEvent")*

```
    Sub ImportDataFromCSV()
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim decisionEventSheet As Worksheet
    Dim csvFile As String
    Dim csvFilePath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Set the source folder path
    sourceFolder = " C:\Users\Juan_Sans_Eros\Documents\Data Extract import test"
    
    ' Set a reference to the DecisionEvent sheet
    Set decisionEventSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DecisionEvent")
    
    ' Check each file in the source folder
    csvFile = Dir(sourceFolder & "\*DecisionEventWFAD*.csv")
    Do While csvFile <> ""
    csvFilePath = sourceFolder & "\" & csvFile
        
    ' Open the CSV file
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=csvFilePath
        
    ' Copy the data to the DecisionEvent sheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = decisionEventSheet.Cells(decisionEventSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.UsedRange.Copy decisionEventSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1)
        
    ' Close the CSV file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    ' Find the next CSV file
    csvFile = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Check each file in the source folder
    csvFile = Dir(sourceFolder & "\*DecisionEventWFCH*.csv")
    Do While csvFile <> ""
    csvFilePath = sourceFolder & "\" & csvFile
        
    ' Open the CSV file
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=csvFilePath
        
    ' Copy the data to the DecisionEvent sheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = decisionEventSheet.Cells(decisionEventSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.UsedRange.Copy decisionEventSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1)
        
    ' Close the CSV file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    ' Find the next CSV file
    csvFile = Dir
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Data imported successfully."
    End Sub
```

Comment: The error means, there is no sheet called "DecisionEvent"

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Your comment prompted me to double check as I was certain that there was indeed a sheet named DecisionEvent.  I discovered that the problem was I was trying to rub the code from VBA rather than from inside the workbook with the decision event sheet.

Comment: My next task is to edit the import criteria so that it does not import the top row from the CSV file.

Comment: probably easier to just delete the row once you've pasted it into excel. So just paste the entire CSV and then delete the row you don't want